# Is this exploration bonus per turn or one-time?

Tags: endless-space

I have got an exploration bonus, and it gives me the choice of 1 ability point on my hero, 15 research, or 30 gold. Are the research and gold bonuses per turn or one time only?

Answer (score 2):

It is a one time bonus. If research or gold income is increased by an event, it is always clearly stated as such, and always time-limited.